# How many users connected on Nginx

Tags: nginx

I am doing some little stress tests on my Nginx server.

I was wondering if there is a way to get some Nginx live status like how many users are connected, and so on ... ?

Thanks for your help guys.

Cheers,
Julien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx has a module for retrieving certain statistics, I haven't used it myself but it appears to be what you're searching for.

[HttpStubStatusModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpStubStatusModule)

Comment: Tank you very much

Answer (score 5):

I use StubStatusModule with the following configuration:

```
location /nginx_status {
                stub_status on;
                access_log   off;
                allow xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
                deny all;
        }
```

Comment: No problem. We are all here to help, not for the Karma :)